# set dynamically colspan jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting `table rows` dynamically. When there are more than `4` rows, `table` is too big and I have to cut it.

The idea is, when there is `5th row` coming, it goes into `second column` of `previous row`, so there are still `4` rows, where `last row` has `2 columns`. And then I'm trying to set `colspan="2"` for the `rows` that have `1 col`.

But the thing is it doesn't want to work. I'm stuck with that for 2 days now and i can't find any idea for it... Would really love to hear any tips from You. Thanks in advance.

I've tried also setting `colspan="2"` into `generateTD() function` - no effects so far.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
function generateTD(){
  var output = '';
  for(var i=1; i<7; i++){
    output += '<tr>';
    if(i<5){
      output += '<td class="merged-col">Row#'+[i]+'</td>';
      if(i>=4){
        output += '<td>Row#'+[i]+'</td>';
      }
    }
    output += '</tr>';
   }
  container.innerHTML = output;
}

generateTD();
$('.merged-col').attr('colspan', 2);
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="container"></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate rows and columns.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
function generateTD(){
  var output = '';
  for(var i=1; i<7; i++){
    output += '<tr>';
    if(i < 4){
      output += '<td class="merged-col">Row#'+[i]+'</td>';
      //if(i>=4){
      //  output += '<td>Row#'+[i]+'</td>';
      //}
    }
    else{
       output += '<td>Row#'+[i]+'</td>';
       output += '<td>Row#'+[i]+'</td>';
    }
    output += '</tr>';
   }
  container.innerHTML = output;
}

generateTD();
$('.merged-col').attr('colspan', 2);
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="container"></table>
```